# Manually call Spellchecker in TinyMCE 4

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am trying to upgrade to TinyMCE 4 and am having issues with manually starting the spellchecker. It seems that this doesn't work any more:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceSpellCheck',false,'');
```

Any suggestions?

Also, in reviewing the JS code, it appears that "mceSpellCheck" was removed from the spellcheck js file. So, how do you call those methods directly anymore in TinyMCE 4?

Answer (score 1):

In the latest TinyMCE 4.2.6 that should work:

```
tinymce.init({
    //... code and setup here
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('init',function(e) {
            editor.execCommand('mceSpellCheck');
        });
    },
    //... and more here perhaps
});
```

Comment: Just wanted to confirm this works for TinyMCE 5 too.